# How to redirect with slugs using Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4.2

I have the following controller:

```
public function postupdate($subject, $id)

//my code

return Redirect::route('webupdate'); // This code is wrong
```

The route below is where I want to redirect to but how do I redirect while including both slugs from the controller above?

Route:

```
Route::get('/updateweb/{subject}/{id}/', array( 'as' => 'webupdate', 'uses' => 'WebController@updatefunc'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  return Redirect::route('webupdate', ['subject'=>$subject, 'id'=>$id]);
```

**OR**

```
  return Redirect::route('webupdate', [$subject, $id]);
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I want the slugs included in the url when I redirect. btw im using Laravel 4.2

Comment: Try the first option. This will redirect the user to the roue `webupdate` with the `$subject`  and `$id`.

Comment: You want the user to redirect to the url `/updateweb/{subject}/{id}/`. Right?

Comment: Yeah but I get `/updateweb/` and not `/update/{subject}/{id}/`

Comment: Do you have any other route named the same name? `webupdate` ? Can you post all your routes?

Comment: no `webupdate` is the only route name with that name. My routes file is too big. But thanks for your help

Comment: Can you try to redirect to the action? `return Redirect::action('WebController@updatefunc', array($subject, $id));`

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
return Redirect::route('webupdate', array($subject, $id));
```

or

```
return Redirect::route('webupdate', array('subject' => $subject, 'id' => $id));
```

If you have only one slug, you could also do

```
return Redirect::route('routename', $id);
```

Read more about [Redirects in Laravel 4.2 here](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#redirects)

Comment: What's the difference from my answer?

Comment: you now added the keys to your answer. @JilsonThomas

Comment: checked already. the second edit was not correct am I false? you did use something like `redirect->route`. wheres the problem, the conversation is made in your answer, so keep on answering and solve his issue ;) I also think that he has duplicated route names

Comment: yeah I recognized the helper function is not available in 4.2

Comment: for some reason it doesnt allow me to post to the database and post a new slug to a different url. This is based on the fact that I can `Redirect::back()` and that `updateweb/{subject}/{id}/` works if I just type this straight into the browser

Comment: @Billy if you show us a little bit more of your important source codes, it would be much easier to find the bug.. and why you cant "post" to the database

Comment: @ahmet2106 thanks for your help but just to clarify I can post to the db I just can't redirect but I've actually decided to use a complete different solution anyway thx